# How to view the messageId of a message in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I'm using a `QueueBrowser` to get a message from the queue, but I can't get the messageId. For some reason my userId is displayed

```java
private void viewMessage() throws NamingException, JMSException {
    Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("dynamicQueues/" + "TestQueue");
    if (queueBrowser == null){
        queueBrowser = queueSession.createBrowser(queue);
    }
    Enumeration<Message> messageEnumeration =  queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
    ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    while (messageEnumeration.hasMoreElements()){
        messages.add(messageEnumeration.nextElement());
    }
    messages.forEach(value -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(value.getJMSMessageID());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
    
}
```

This is what is displayed in my console:
[image]

Messages in queue:
[image]

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is correct. Keep in mind that ActiveMQ Artemis is a multi-protocol broker so the value set by the JMS client (i.e. via `setJMSMessageID`) is *not* the same as the internal message ID assigned by the broker. The ID set by the core JMS client is referred to as the "User ID" in the web console.

Comment: When sending a message, a message identifier is generated, that is, a unique message value. The question is, how do I get it?

Comment: You use `getJMSMessageID` just like you already are. The value that's generated when you send the message will be unique to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Artemis the "User ID" of the message displayed in the console is the "Message ID" set by the sending client (user). It is a little confusing but that is the value that JMS client would have set on the message as Its JMS Message ID on send.  The message ID value you see is the broker created ID for the message it received from a sender and is used for internal tracking.

Comment: When sending a message, a message identifier is generated, that is, a unique message value. The question is, how do I get it?

Comment: You use `getJMSMessageID` just like you already are. The value that's generated when you send the message will be unique to it.